# Prove formula involving matrix exponential

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis

Let $A \in L(X)$. Prove for all $x \in X$:

$$e^{tA}x=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{t^k}{k!}A^kx+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{(t-s)^n}{n!}e^{sA}A^{n+1}xds$$

My first guess would have been to write $e^{tA}x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(tA)^k}{k!}x$. Splitting this sum at $k=n$ gives me the first part of the formula I want to prove, the second part is $\sum_{k=n}^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{k!}A^kx$ which should evaluate to this integral? Unfortunately though I was unable to solve this integral.

The second part of the task is to show that for all $t >0$: If $||e^{tA}||\leq1$ then for all $x \in X$ we have $||Ax||^2 \leq 4||x||||A^2x||$. The hint is to set $n=1$ in the above formula and then choose an optimal $t$ but unfortunately I'm also stuck on this part.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The formula is very reminiscent of the Taylor theorem with remainder in integral form, see e.g. here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem. I would guess that you can adapt the proof of this remainder formula to fit your situation.

Comment: I believe the integral _could_ be solved using integration by parts $n$ times.